# How should I overwrite/replace nmap, when there are two copies of the same version present?

Tags: homebrew, nmap, macos-big-sur

I recently reinstalled nmap using brew, which, I guess, has caused some conflict with the pre-existing one. So just running `nmap` gives a `-bash: /usr/local/bin/nmap:` error.

Ran `brew doctor` to diagnose the issue and came up with this:

`Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar. Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run 'brew link' on these: nmap`

`Warning: Broken symlinks were found. Remove them with 'brew cleanup': /usr/local/share/man/man1/brew-cask.1`

I tried running `brew link --overwrite nmap`
but gives me error: `Could not symlink share/man/es/man1/nmap.1 Target /usr/local/share/man/es/man1/nmap.1 already exists. You may want to remove it: rm '/usr/local/share/man/es/man1/nmap.1'`

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can just follow the indications given by `brew doctor` by running:

```
rm '/usr/local/share/man/es/man1/nmap.1'
```

then

```
brew link --overwrite nmap
```